# How to convert a table into summary as shown

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have table as below. I want to add rows for a category and sum all (excluding null) same species (say lemon), same species length under each category
[image: demo].
Now i want to consolidate the table as shown- adding rows under each category should be of different length and automatic e.g. there may not be all 120 species under A .

N.B. I tried pivot but failed. I have more than 100 species and 1000 categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PivotTable can help in that case though. The source data should be placed in rows, like records in a database. Here is an example of pivot table setup.

1. Copy the source range.

[image: Copy the source range]

2. Paste and transpose.

[image: Paste and transpose]

3. Build pivot table on the transposed data.

[image: Build pivot table]

[image: Build pivot table]

4. Drag category names "A", "B" and "C" from the top to the "Values" area.

[image: Drag category names to the "Values" area]

5. Change a type of calculation from "Count" to "Sum" for each of category names.

[image: Change a type of calculation]

[image: Change a type of calculation]

**UPDATE for items 4 and 5**

If there are a lot of categories, you can automate the items 4 and 5 - run the below macro to move all fields (but the first one) to the "Values" area with "Sum" type of calculation:

```vb
Sub AddDataFields()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
        Set objPivotFields = .PivotFields
        For i = 2 To objPivotFields.Count
            Set objPivotField = objPivotFields(i)
            Debug.Print objPivotField.Caption
            .AddDataField objPivotField, "Sum of " & objPivotField.Caption, xlSum
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

6. Drag appeared "Σ Values" field from "Column Labels" to "Row Labels" area, drag "Category" from the top to the "Row Labels" area.

[image: Drag "Σ Values" and "Category" fields]

7. Change report layout to tabular form.

[image: Change report layout]

8. As a result you have now the species and length sums in one column.

[image: species and length sums in one column]

9. You can setup a label filter to retrieve only species sums.

[image: setup a label filter]

[image: setup a label filter]

[image: setup a label filter]

Comment: I approached this process but you have to track down all 120 species +120 species length in VALUE (sum) field that is hard..

Comment: @SIslam There are categories ("A", "B" and "C") in "Σ Values" field you have to track down, but not all species.

Comment: Oh! sorry over than 1000 categories..

Comment: @SIslam check my update for items 4 and 5.

Comment: I am getting error http://i.imgur.com/5XJO4QT.png

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example that might help you:

[image]

This probably calls for the [SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function which works roughly like this:

```
foreach element in range {
    if element == criteria {
        sum = sum + corresponding element in sum_range
    }
}
return sum
```

In this case, you'd put something like (refer to my screenshot):

```
C9 = SUMIF(1:1;B9;2:2)
```

which scans through the entire first row and everytime it finds a label matching what you put in cell B11, it takes the corresponding value in row 2.

For the species length sum, you can just use the `CONCATENATE` function of excel by doing:

```
D9 = SUMIF(1:1;CONCATENATE(B9;"_length");2:2)
```

Hope this helps.

Oh, one more thing, to keep the references constant as you drag along so that you can fill multiple cells, put a `$` in to the reference:

```
C9 = SUMIF($1:$1;B9;$2:$2)
```

This way, only B9 changes as you drag down to reference B10, B11, and so on.

Comment: Ah! I have more than 100 species and more than 1000 categories- there wil be so many sheets if i split...!

Comment: I see. How are you arranging your categories? Are they cycling 1,2,3,1,2,3? Would the "summing every nth row" thing work?

Comment: Noops categories are unique.. No repeatation

Comment: Alright, I've edited my answer to give you a different approach. Let me know if it's what you need!

Comment: @ Wizongod I appreciate your help! But i am sweating in making rows (over 100 for each category) for each species under each category. Now i am open to VBA since i think there is no resort to create empty rows but VBA. Infact i need only those species and species_length that have value greater that 0- not all 120 spcies...